# Do all my team need XP+ items when grinding or only the active members?

Tags: star-ocean-4

In star ocean 4 you can get XP+ items which boost the amount of XP from any battle, appently upto some high figure like 680%+;

I understand how to get the items too boost my weapon, accessory and neck item however do I need to do this just for the team I have actively fighting, or everyone? Do I need 8 of each item + all their weapons, or just the 4 I use for fighting and then swap them out one by one (Swapping the accessory and neck items over)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the current fighting team need the items, so you only need 4 neck items and 4 wrist items to have a full team of +XP items; (the rest comes from their weapons).